Automate google script and how?
I have the below code.
Works great. When I click run it finds first link posts and marks as posted.
The manual trigger works at every hour (if I start it on the hour)
My question is: how do I or can someone type up for me.
How to do a trigger so it runs every Monday starting at 8am every hour to 12am
Thank you in advanced.
function postToDiscord(currentMessage) const url = 

 const message = content: currentMessage

 const options = ( method' : 'post' payload message

 const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)

function mondaycurrentLiveLinks()f

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Live Links")

 const messageCell = ws.getRange(ws.getMaxRows(),2).getNextDataCell (SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).offset(1,-1)

 const currentMessage = messageCell.getValue()

if(currentMessage ==

"") return

postToDiscord(currentMessage

messageCell.offset(0,1).setValue(

posted")

Triggers work to an extent but going in every morning to run the daily script for that week isn't what I want to do

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The code has problems. It is missing characters required by JavaScript syntax, among other things. Please fix the code. Also, the question is unclear.

Learn how to post  and - format code Separate your function definitions

The code works fine my question is there a trigger or manual code I can place so it runs every Monday every hour

The code you posted does not work fine.  PLease fix and format properly and we may then answer your question.

You can use a timebased trigger.  It would use one that runs every hour and decide in the code which one to use.  Look at the event object in -Time Based Trigger

My current proposal is:

Create a weekly trigger that runs the creation of the hourly trigger
The hourly trigger will run your script/acting function each hour
Create another weekly trigger that deletes the hourly trigger

I could be somehthing like this
function repetition() {

  // Create and store the hourly trigger
  var hourlyTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('MyRun')
    .timeBased()
    .everyHours(1)
    .create();
    userProperties.setProperty('HourlyTrigger', hourlyTrigger.getUniqueId());
    Logger.log(hourlyTrigger.getUniqueId())

}


function setTriggers() {

  // Create and store the weekly trigger 1
  var weeklyTrigger1 = ScriptApp.newTrigger('repetition')
    .timeBased()
    .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
    .everyWeeks(1)
    .atHour(9)
    .inTimezone('America/Los_Angeles')
    .create();
    userProperties.setProperty('WeeklyTrigger1', weeklyTrigger1.getUniqueId());
    Logger.log(weeklyTrigger1.getUniqueId())


  // Create and store the weekly trigger 2
  var weeklyTrigger2 = ScriptApp.newTrigger('deleteTriggerByName')
    .timeBased()
    .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY)
    .everyWeeks(1)
    .atHour(0)
    .inTimezone('America/Los_Angeles')
    .create();
    userProperties.setProperty('WeeklyTrigger2', weeklyTrigger2.getUniqueId());
    Logger.log(weeklyTrigger2.getUniqueId())
    
}

function deleteTriggerByName() {
  var trs = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var triggerId = userProperties.getProperty('HourlyTrigger');
  // Logger.log(triggerId)
  for (i = 0; i < trs.length; i ++){
    Logger.log(trs[i].getUniqueId(), 'this is 1')
    if (trs[i].getUniqueId() === triggerId) {
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trs[i])
        Logger.log('Deleted trigger with ID: ' + triggerId);
        break;
      }
  }

}

